# C# basic dictionary (hash) implementation

Tags: c#, reinventing-the-wheel, hash-map

I have implemented a very basic hash data structure with basic set/retrieve methods.
A good example of use of this implementation would be a phone-book.
I have used as underneath storage structure an array consisting of linked lists.

Please a code review within these requirements.

```
public class MyHash
{
    private LinkedList<string>[] storage;

    public MyHash()
    {
        storage = new LinkedList<string>[26]; //english alphabet
    }

    private int HashFunction(string key)
    {
        //maps first character of name to a 0:25 index
        return key.ToLower().ToCharArray()[0] - 97;
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get {
            var list = storage[HashFunction(key)];
            if (list != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    if (item.Split(':')[0] == key)
                        return item.Split(':')[1];
                }
            }
            return "Not found!";
        }
        set {
            if (storage[HashFunction(key)] == null)
                storage[HashFunction(key)] = new LinkedList<string>();
            storage[HashFunction(key)].AddLast(key + ":" + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you call this a dictionary when there is none?

Comment: Also why do you add items as `key + ":" + value` if you split it later and get the second item. What if a value contains a `:` too? Why don't you simply add `value`? Very weird.

Comment: I need to use {key}:{value} to retrieve it, when multiple entries exists in the same slot. Example if 'Joan', 'John' & 'Joel' are stored and 'John' phone number is needed.

Comment: @JoanDimko: as t3chb0t already pointed out, that approach will cause problems with keys and values that contain `:` characters. Another problem is that your class fails to handle keys that don't start with `a-z`: keys like `"1"` or `"中"` cause an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Yet another problem is that `"Not found!"` could actually be a valid input value, and besides that it's an undocumented 'magic' value. Besides that, you may want to be more specific in what kind of feedback you're looking for - is this for educational purposes, or for actual use?

Comment: @ Pieter Witvoet thanks for comment. It is an isolated use case of a phonebook for educational purpose. I want to know if this piece of code implements correctly a basic hash table with basic set/retrieval functions. Do not worry for any exception, just focus on the core of a basic hash table structure.

Comment: I don't see a tag of reinventing-the-wheel, so I must ask the obvious: why not use the Dictionary object already in the framework?

Comment: How can you call it a dictionary or hash table?  It allows duplicate keys.  Why use LinkedList over List?

Comment: Part of me wants to VTC because I think a lot of the comments above could be considered "broken" code, but could also indicate poor design. I'm not voting to close because I think the implementation is in general functional, and the design choices make for a fun review with lots of things to leave feedback on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several (major) problems with this class:

- Keys that contain a `:` character cannot be used to look up their value, and values that contain a `:` character are only partially returned. Also, this class cannot handle `null` values (it returns an empty string instead). Don't mash keys and values together into a single value, using a key-value object instead (such as `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`).
- Keys that start with anything but `[a-zA-Z]` cause an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. This is not documented anywhere, and there's no obvious reason why such keys shouldn't be allowed (phone books aren't limited to countries with a Latin alphabet, after all). Why not use the modulus of the hash value and the number of buckets?
- Non-existing keys produce a 'magic' value, which isn't documented anywhere. Moreover, a caller won't be able to distinguish between a non-existing key and an actual (valid) `"Not found!"` value. You may want to throw an exception instead. Alternately, you could provide a `TryGetValue` method instead.
- Overwriting the value for an existing key is not possible. Your class will store both values (why?), but lookups will continue to return the first value. I would expect the new entry to replace the earlier one. If that's not the intended behavior, then I'd expect that to be documented, and an appropriate exception to be thrown.
- Your hash function is poorly chosen. Ideally, you'll want to spread entries across buckets as evenly as possible, so each lookup will take roughly the same amount of time on average. If items are concentrated in only a few buckets (some characters are more frequently used than others) then lookups for such keys will be slower. Why not use `key.GetHashCode()` instead, or let the caller provide a hashing method in the constructor?
- Using a fixed number of buckets means that lookup times are essentially \$O(n)\$, not \$O(1)\$. Locating a bucket takes constant time, while searching through multiple entries in a bucket takes linear time, so you'll want to limit the number of entries per bucket (ideally to 1). That requires some kind of resizing strategy.

Other minor issues:

- By calling `Split(':')` and `HashFunction` multiple times you're doing the same work repeatedly. Just call them once and store the result in a variable.
- Some names could be clarified a bit: `MyHashTable` or `MyHashMap` instead of `MyHash`, and `buckets` instead of `storage`.
- Going for a generic implementation would not only be of more practical use, it would also have helped you to avoid some of the above problems: you wouldn't have been able to mash keys and values together or to use a sub-optimal leading-character 'hash'.